# Remove visible class after it reach 100% opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this line to create a fade-in effect.

```
$('#div').css({opacity: 0, visibility:"visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
```

Is it possible to completely remove the visible class after it reach 100%? So basically I need to do `$('#div').css('opacity','');` when it reach `opacity: 1`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the complete callback to remove the class

```
$('#div').css({
    opacity: 0,
    visibility: "visible"
}).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 500, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('visible')
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and it does not remove the inline classes?

Comment: It works if i do `.css('opacity','');`. How can I write both `'opacity'` and `'visible'` classes in a single line?

Comment: @Bekki sorry.. what do you mean

Comment: I'm using inline css. When I tried this `$(this).removeClass('visible')` it does not remove the visible class. I tried `$(this).css({'opacity':'', 'visible':''});` then the inline opacity is removed but the visible class stays. How can I remove both visible and opacity classes.  Please note that the css are inline css.

Comment: @Bekki `$(this).removeClass('visible').css({'opacity':'', 'visible':''})`

Comment: thanks but this removes only the opacity class. The visible class stays?

Comment: oh I figured it out. :D it's `'visibility':''` not `'visible':''`.